# Find the equation of a plane that contains a given line and is parallel to a given plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Question says: Find the equation of the plane that contains the line $x=1+t, y=2-t, z=4-3t$ and is parallel to the plane $5x+2y+z=1$.

So far I figured the direction vector of the line is $<1,-1,-3>$ and that the symmetric equation of the line is $x-1=2-y=\frac{z-4}{-3}$. But I am lost on how to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plane $P$ you're looking for is parallel to the one given by $5x+2y+z=1$.
Thus
$P$ has an equation of the form $$5x+2y+z=\alpha\tag{1}$$ where $\alpha$ is a constant that we need to determine. That's because both planes are orthogonal to vector $(5, 2, 1)$.

To do that, remember $P$ to contain that one line. So any point on that line should be on the plane. Let's pick the point $C=(1, 2, 4)$, which is definitely on that line (I found it by taking $t=0$).

Let's plug the coordinates of $C$ inside $(1)$:
$$ 5\times 1 + 2\times 2 + 1\times 4 = \alpha = 13$$
Thus $P$ has equation
$$ 5x+2y+z=13$$